# setState not setting the value correctly in react native (expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, setstate

I am setting a value to useState hook on a button press but not working.

```
const [text, setText] = useState("")

const demo = () => {
   setText("Hello world")
   alert(text)
}


<TouchableOpacity onPress={demo}>
   <Text>set Value</Text
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setText` is async function.
If you `alert(text)` old value will be alerted.

You should `useEffect`

```js
const [text, setText] = useState("")

const demo = () => {
  setText("Hello world")
}

useEffect(() => {
  alert(text)
}, [text])


<TouchableOpacity onPress={demo}>
   <Text>set Value</Text
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState`is asynchronous, that means that when you call alert with the param "text" is not assigned yet, in the second call (if you press two times) will be displayed with the correct value.

Comment: Is there a way to alert the value without clicking twice?